# Should I unescape some characters if using a tool like NicEdit for posts? How?

Tags: mysql, post, escaping, mysql-real-escape-string

I'm planning on using nicEdit for posts to allow users to change the text font, weight, add a picture... But my question is, before using mysql_real_escape_string should I unescape some characters? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try with: ... = stripslashes($_POST['foo']);